# Vagrant installation on windows 10

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

This is my first time trying to use vagrant. I've downloaded and installed virtual box and vagrant , and also a vagrant config file.
Using guide at [this](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/) link, I typed :

```
$ vagrant init hashicorp/precise64
$ vagrant up
```

I've faced with something like this:

```
D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/win32/registry.rb:71:in `find': unknown encoding name - CP720 (ArgumentError)
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/win32/registry.rb:71:in `<module:Win32>'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/win32/registry.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/win32/resolv.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:169:in `<class:Hosts>'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:166:in `<class:Resolv>'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:36:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:87:in `<class:LockfileParser>'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:14:in `<module:Bundler>'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:155:in `definition'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:123:in `setup'
    from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/bin/vagrant:71:in `<main>'
```

I couldn't find anything useful online.
Any kind of suggestion would be appreciated.
I've rebooted my PC and also tried git bash with administrative privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to run

```
$ chcp.com 1252
Active code page: 1252
```

from https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6736

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the [Code Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) 
To do this use [CHCP](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) command as the following: 
`$ chcp.com 1252
Active code page: 1252`